# Wildfly CLI - "jms-queue" not in the command list

Tags: command-line-interface, jms, wildfly, activemq-artemis

I'm trying to build a CLI script to configure my `WildFly 29` server. The Wildfly starts with the standard `standalone.xml`.
But after starting the script I get the message that the command `jms-queue` is not included in the command list.

```
Unexpected command 'jms-queue add --queue-address=TestQueue --entries=java:/jms/queue/test'. Type 'help --commands' for the list of supported commands.
```

Only when I restart the CLI console can I access the commands.

```
batch
    /extension=org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq:add
    reload
run-batch

batch
    /subsystem=messaging-activemq:add
    /:reload
    /subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default:add(elytron-domain="ApplicationDomain")
    /subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/security-setting=#:add
    /subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/address-setting=#:add(dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ", expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue", expiry-delay=-1L, max-delivery-attempts="10", max-size-bytes="10485760", page-size-bytes="2097152", message-counter-history-day-limit="10")
    /subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/http-connector=http-connector:add(socket-binding="http", endpoint="http-acceptor")
    /subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/http-connector=http-connector-throughput:add(socket-binding="http", endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput" ,params={batch-delay="50"})
    /subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/in-vm-connector=in-vm:add(server-id="0")
    /subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/http-acceptor=http-acceptor:add(http-listener="default")
    /subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/http-acceptor=http-acceptor-throughput:add(http-listener="default", params={batch-delay="50", direct-deliver="false"})
    /subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/in-vm-acceptor=in-vm:add(server-id="0")
    /subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/jms-queue=ExpiryQueue:add(entries=["java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"])
    /subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/jms-queue=DLQ:add(entries=["java:/jms/queue/DLQ"])
    /:reload
    /subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/connection-factory=InVmConnectionFactory:add(connectors=["in-vm"], entries=["java:/ConnectionFactory"])
    /subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/connection-factory=RemoteConnectionFactory:add(connectors=["http-connector"], entries = ["java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"])
    /subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/pooled-connection-factory=activemq-ra:add(transaction="xa", connectors=["in-vm"], entries=["java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory"])
    /subsystem=ee/service=default-bindings/:write-attribute(name="jms-connection-factory", value="java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory")
    /subsystem=ejb3:write-attribute(name="default-resource-adapter-name", value="${ejb.resource-adapter-name:activemq-ra.rar}")
    /subsystem=ejb3:write-attribute(name="default-mdb-instance-pool", value="mdb-strict-max-pool")
    /:reload
    jms-queue add --queue-address=TestQueue --entries=java:/jms/queue/test
run-batch
/:reload
```

I execute the script with this call:

```
jboss-cli.bat --connect --file=Config_Wildfly.cli --echo-command
```

Which command do I use to refresh the CLI console so that the jms commands are listed?

Comment: iirc those high level commands are only loaded into the cli if the extension is loaded which would require a restart. you could use classic commands though (but in the same way the model is only available when the extension is loaded) which is what your first batch does. Using the standalone-full.xml would be the better way to do this in my humble opinion.